# LINUX AWK command to merge isoform of genes

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a large file in the following format:

```
chr1    11873   12227   DDX11L1 .   +
chr1    12612   12721   DDX11L1 .   +
chr1    13220   14409   DDX11L1 .   +
chr1    14361   14829   WASH7P  .   -
chr1    14969   15038   WASH7P  .   -
chr1    15795   15947   WASH7P  .   -
chr1    16606   16765   WASH7P  .   -
chr1    16857   17055   WASH7P  .   -
chr1    17232   17368   WASH7P  .   -
chr1    17368   17436   MIR6859-2   .   -
chr1    17368   17436   MIR6859-1   .   -
chr1    17605   17742   WASH7P  .   -
chr1    17914   18061   WASH7P  .   -
chr1    18267   18366   WASH7P  .   -
chr1    24737   24891   WASH7P  .   -
chr1    29320   29370   WASH7P  .   -
chr1    34610   35174   FAM138A .   -
chr1    34610   35174   FAM138F .   -
chr1    35276   35481   FAM138A .   -
chr1    35276   35481   FAM138F .   -
chr1    35720   36081   FAM138A .   -
chr1    35720   36081   FAM138F .   -
chr1    69090   69093   OR4F5   .   +
chr1    69090   70005   OR4F5   .   +
chr1    69090   70008   OR4F5   .   +
chr1    70005   70008   OR4F5   .   +
chr1    134772  139696  LOC729737   .   -
chr1    139789  139847  LOC729737   .   -
```

I want to merge coordinates of all isoforms (coloumn 4) of a gene.
If the values in column four is same within column, I want values in column 2 of first matching line and value of column 3 in last matching line.so the output will become.

```
chr1    11873   14409   DDX11L1 .   +
chr1    14361   29370   WASH7P  .   -
chr1    17368   17436   MIR6859-2   .   -
chr1    17368   17436   MIR6859-1   .   -
chr1    34610   36081   FAM138A .   -
chr1    34610   36081   FAM138F .   -
chr1    69090   70008   OR4F5   .   +
chr1    134772  139847  LOC729737   .   -
```

Thanks in advance, looking forward for a positive response.

Comment: Why did you tag this awk/sed? I see no awk or sed code in the question. - Actually I see no question at all.

Comment: i think there is possibility to use awk command to get desired output

Comment: You should at least have learned how to format the sample input/output from your first question.

Comment: sorry, but i didn't get what you want to say .

Answer (score 3):

Use this `awk`:

```
awk '!a[$4]{b[i++]=$0} {a[$4]=$3} END{for(i in b){$0=b[i];$3=a[$4];print}}' file
```

- `!a[$4]`: applies to every line where the 4th field appears first

  - `b[i++]=$0`: in that case, fill the array `b` with those lines
- `{a[$4]=$3}` appies to every line. The array `a` is filled with the 3rd field, which when done, stores the last values of the 3rd field.
- `END{...}` will be executed when all lines are processed

  - `for(i in b)` loops trough the array `b`.
  - `$0=b[i]` sets the `$0` variable
  - `$3=a[$4]` the 3rd field should be the last occurence
  - `print` print the line

---

The output:

```
chr1 11873 14409 DDX11L1 . +
chr1 14361 29370 WASH7P . -
chr1 17368 17436 MIR6859-2 . -
chr1 17368 17436 MIR6859-1 . -
chr1 34610 36081 FAM138A . -
chr1 34610 36081 FAM138F . -
chr1 69090 70008 OR4F5 . +
chr1 134772 139847 LOC729737 . -
```

---

If you want it columnated, use this:

```
awk ... | column -t
```

Comment: This is ingenious. Do note however that it stores the entire output in memory before printing it. Depending on how large "large" is, there is a potential pitfall there.

Comment: @JeffY Yes, thats true, but I see no other way. The file could have the first occurence in the first line and the last occurence in the last line (theoretically). So we have to loop over the whole file before printing anything...

Comment: True, unless you can pre-condition the data using an external sort guaranteed to be stable (not change the order of equal-key records). I assumed learner really wanted min2 and max3 rather than first2 and and last3 in my solution below. But I see now that Unix (cygwin) sort is in fact external and also has a -s stable option, so even a first2/last3 might be possible in O(1) memory if that's what learner really needs...

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you want minimum col2 and maximum col3.

```
sort -k4 -k2n|
awk '$4!=p4{if(NR>1)print p1,min,max,p4,p5,p6;
            p1=$1;min=$2;max=$3;p4=$4;p5=$5;p6=$6;}
     $4=p4{if($3>max)max=$3}
     END{print p1,min,max,p4,p5,p6}'|
sort -k2n
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and sort):

```
sort -sk4,4 file |
sed -r ':a;$!N;s/^((\S+\s+){2})\S+\s+(\S+)\s+.*\s+(\S+\s+\3)/\1\4/;ta;P;D'|
sort -sk2,2n
```

Sort the file by the fourth column but retain the original order.

Read two lines at a time, reducing lines with matching fourth columns to a single line and retaining the third column from the latest line.

Sort the output of the above process numerically by the second column (again retaining the original order).